# Persistent use of loop block device in mdadm

Tags: linux, mount, raid, loop-device

I have multiple external storage-spaces which can be mounted with `samba/cifs`.
Over these spaces I want to create a raid device.

My idea was the creation of data files with

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/extStorages/storage[0..x]/data
```

Now I created loop devices with

```
losetup /dev/loop[0..x] /extStorages/storage[0..x]/data
```

And create the raid device on top of the loop devices

```
mdadm --create /dev/md/md0 --level=<level> --raid-devices=x /dev/loop0 .. /dev/loopx
mkfs.ext4 /dev/md/md0
mount /dev/md/md0 /Storage
```

This is working until the next reboot as the loop devices are not persistent.
Therefore mounting the raid on `fstab` isn't possible.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a init.d script which start and stop the volume:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          networkRaid
# Required-Start:    $network $named $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: handles the 'network raid'
### END INIT INFO


PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start() {
  losetup /dev/loop0 /extDrives/drive0/data
  losetup /dev/loop1 /extDrives/drive1/data
  losetup /dev/loop2 /extDrives/drive2/data

  mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2

  mount /dev/md0 /Storage
}

do_stop() {
  umount /Storage

  mdadm --stop /dev/md0

  losetup -d /dev/loop0
  losetup -d /dev/loop1
  losetup -d /dev/loop2
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    do_start
        exit 0
        ;;
    restart|reload|force-reload)
        echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
    stop|status)
        do_stop
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

For persistency you have to write things to the mdamd config file:

```
mdadm --verbose --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf
```

To setup the loop devices explicitly I normally add some code in the `/etc/rc.local`. If you need to that, you can mount the raid from there as well.