# Cache for file system

Tags: filesystems, cache

I have setup a 'network-raid" file system as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302766/persistent-use-of-loop-block-device-in-mdadm).

Now I want to add a local cache for it. I found `cachefilesd` which looks like it would do what I need but it is only for `afs` and `nfs`.

Is there some other cache system available which I can attach to my 'network-raid'?

-- Tolotos

EDIT: I tried `nfs` selfmounting and it looks like its working. But is there a better option out there?